# Python script to Windows exe file with cx-freeze under ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, windows, exe, ubuntu-12.04, cx-freeze

I would like create Windows exe file in Ubuntu 12.04 from a Python script.

```
apt-get install cx-freeze
cd ~/.app/
ls
app.py
```

How to create a Windows XP, Vista, 7 executable of the app.py script?

Comment: Ubuntu's cxFreeze can't create Windows executables. The only thing I can think of that _might_ work is to install Wine, Python for Windows on Wine with cxFreeze, and try to create the executable there.

Comment: I'm sad. I wouldn't like Wine install.

Comment: I've tried with Wine before - it half works, but Wine is missing a key function, so it can't find all the DLLs it needs to copy. If you know the extra files you need, and copy them into the correct folder, you can make the exe work.

Answer (score 3):

Freezing Python code on Linux into a Windows executable was only once supported in PyInstaller and later dropped. Sadly, seems the only solution for now is to install wine, then in wine you will install the windows version of python. From here you should be able to freeze the script into .exe for windows.

Comment: Just to reiterate: you can make an exe using Wine, but it doesn't find all the DLL dependencies, so you need to copy some extra files to make it work.